# How to get data from a JSON to DialogFlow bot?

Tags: json, bots, dialogflow-es

Hi Im a beginner to DialogFlow (Api.ai) and I want to make a currency converter. I have a json file hosted on 000 webhost and it look like this.

```
{
  "currency": [
    {
      "currency": "USD",
      "buying": "158.70",
      "selling": "162.50",
     },
     {
      "currency": "GBP",
      "buying": "190.00",
      "selling": "195.98",
     },

  ]
}
```

I want to get exchange rates from this JSON and display on DialogFlow bot when the user tells which currency they want.
Eg: user asks bot to show USD rates and bot should get data from json and display to the user.

How should I do this? please help. Hope my English is clear since English isnt my native language. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you had like to write the response. You can either directly add your responses in dialogflow or can write a webhook to parse the request & send a response. Webhook is something where your actual business logic lies.

If you want to send your own json as given in your question, you can consider writing custom payload in dialogflow.

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": 4,
      "payload": {
        "currency": [{
           "currency": "USD",
           "buying": "158.70",
           "selling": "162.50"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Writing custom payload has different format depending on your integration channel. https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages#custom_payload. If want to go by webhook, please check https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment. Hope, this answers your query.